# Sonata Admin ManyToOne error: "sonata_type_collection - mapping : 2 "

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I want to use Sonata Admin Gallery feature into my `News Entity`.
Here is my code

**News.yml**

```
....

manyToOne:
    gallery:
        targetEntity: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
        inversedBy: news_gallery
        cascade: ["persist"] 
        nullable: true
```

**Gallery.orm.xml**

```
....

<one-to-many field="news_gallery" 
                 target-entity="Wenweipo\NewsBundle\Entity\News"
                 mapped-by="gallery" />
```

**NewsAdmin.php**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {

    $formMapper
        ->add('gallery', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                    ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position',
                'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'images_news',
                ),
                        'admin_code'=>'sonata.media.admin.gallery_has_media'
            ))

}
```

Now when I run my admin code I receive this error.

```
INVALID MODE : s543e4bf7bc21f_gallery - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping : 2
```

What I m doing wrong?

Comment: try to use `sonata_type_model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your own relation that will hold `NewsHasMeda` like `GalleryHasMedia`

**News.orm.yml**

```
........
oneToMany:
    news_has_media:
        targetEntity: Wenweipo\NewsBundle\Entity\NewsHasMedia
        mappedBy: news 
        cascade: ["persist","remove"]
        orphanRemoval: true
```

Now make another entity named as `NewsHasMedia.yml`.Then in `yml` file add the code like this

**NewsHasMedia.orm.yml**

```
........
fields:

    enabled:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
    position:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
    createdAt:
        type: datetime
        column: created_at
        nullable: true
    updatedAt:
        type: datetime
        column: updated_at
        nullable: true


manyToOne:

    media:
        targetEntity: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        cascade: ["persist"]
        joinColumn:
            name: media_id   
            referencedColumnName: id
            #nullable: true 

    news:
        targetEntity: News
        inversedBy:  news_has_media
        cascade: ["persist"]
        joinColumn:
            name: news_id   
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Then generate this entity.Now in Admin file add this one

**NewsAdmin.php**

```
->add('news_has_media', 'sonata_type_collection', array(

   'cascade_validation' => true), array(

            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position',
            'link_parameters' => array(
                'context' => 'images_news',
            ),

        ))
```

now no need to specify `admin_code`.Hope this will solve your problem.