# Sonata admin dropdown with ajax data results

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I am working on a sonata admin panel using symfony 3.3. I have two entities `Category` and  `Chalets`. They are associated many to many so that One category have many Chalets and Chalet can be associated to many Categories.

I want the functionality in my admin panel to show the Chalets based on Category choosen from dropdown and a button to replicate the same to add another category with Chalets and so on.

The picture below will give you the deep insights.
[Picture of my current functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b54QO.png)

Right now all the Chalets added in the database are visible in the dropdown I want to show only the selected category Chalets to be shown. Alson, the button(Add more) will replicate the Category and Chalet to repeat the process.
Thanks!

Comment: " button to replicate the same" - not clear. What should happen when you press on that button?

Comment: It should clone the `Category` dropdown along with `Chalet` dropdown. To assign multiple categories with chalets.

Answer (score 0):

**What you need is [sonata_type_collection](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-admin) field.**

It will look a bit different out of the box, but capabilities is exactly what you want.

So, how it works:

- sonata_type_collection field will include a table inside of your edit form. Every row in this table is another Category.
- there is possibility to add "Add" and "Delete" buttons, so you could add and delete categories directly from this edit form.
- second column in this embed table could be "Charlets" field, and it can be editable inline (select2 elements). So you can choose charlets for every category.
- when you add Category - it's a "create" form, it has only Category dropdown. But when you edit a row inline - it's an "edit" form, it will has also "Charlets" multi select. And options for this multi select can be generated based on chosen Category.

So, all this will work without any custom templates/Ajax calls.

P S. If you still want to customize UI - easier to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: I have many to many association with Category and Chalets. I tried 'sonata_type_collection' but it asks to add new Chalets. I do not want to create new Chalets, I have chalets already and just want to associate. The screenshot wold give you the better idea.
https://prnt.sc/gjt6ne

Comment: Basically I want chalets and categories to be auto-populated.

Comment: As I suggest here, add sonata_type_collection for Category field, not for Chalet

Comment: It is showing an error:- INVALID_MODE 'sonata_type _collection'. see below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380592/sonata-admin-manytoone-error-sonata-type-collection-mapping-2